# Regex escape all matches for <!here|@here> with @here or blank

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a string, such as this:

```
var myString = 'Hi, <!here|@here>';
```

I'm trying to escape what might be misunderstood as HTML by an API, thought regex is perfect, but I can't figure it out.

Ideal output after running on the above string:

> Hi, @here

This is what I've tried so far:

```
var result = myString.replace(/(<!.*\|.*)@.*(>)/gm,' ');

console.log(string,result);
```

I'm getting a blank response here. Testing with regex101 in the meantime.

Comment: Please provide a real world input / desired output samples.

Comment: I can't figure out what you are trying to replace here.

Comment: Corrected my post, my bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presence of dot-star `.*` - *as being too much greedy* - will probably make problems in a Regular Expression. You don't need trailing and leading dot-stars at all otherwise they would consume everything in your input string.

Also remember to not use dot-star when you want to stop at a specific point as it may not stop at the right place.

```js
var myString = 'Hi, <!here|@here>';
var result = myString.replace(/<!(.*?)\|@\1>/g, '@$1');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: It would be more precise to instead of using a lazy dot-star, use a white-list of characters `<!([^<>|]*)\|@\1>`

Comment: Thanks @revo, the $1 placeholder was the key I wasn't aware of, learnt something new today.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this

```
myString.replace(/(<!.*\|)(.*)>/g, '$2');
```

or lazy regexp version: `/(<!.*?\|)(.*)>/g` (it depends how do you want it to work)